# Why chdir in pysftp library doesn't effect on execute in pysftp library?

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I uses pysftp (it is wrapper of paramiko).

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
sftp=pysftp.Connection(host='hostname',username="root",password="pass",cnopts=cnopts)
```

The script in /home/alex_test and I want to execute the script

```
sftp.chdir("/home/alex_test")
sftp.execute("source myscript.tcsh")
```

But It doesn't work because the script was not found.

In the other hand, It does work

```
sftp.execute("cd /home/alex_test;cat myscript.tcsh")
```

Why ?
My goal is to create a generic code for unix and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The `.execute` methods has actually nothing to do with SFTP. It internally opens a separate "exec" SSH channel. That channel is completely isolated from the "SFTP" subsystem channel.

It would be more clear had you used Paramiko library directly, as there you would clearly see that Paramiko [`SSHClient.exec_command` method](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command) (internally used by pysftp `.execute`) does not use Paramiko [`SFTPClient` class](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html) at all.

Actually even the documentation for [`.execute` method](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.execute) says that:

> Execute the given commands on a remote machine. **The command is executed without regard to the remote `pwd`.**

---

Moreover SFTP protocol itself does not have a concept of a working directory.

The pysftp (or actually the underlying Paramiko library) only simulates that locally. All relative paths that you pass to pysftp/Paramiko library SFTP methods are converted to absolute paths, before they are sent to the SFTP server. For pysftp that means virtually all methods (that work with remote paths), with a notable exception of `.execute`. That conversion is possible only because SFTP protocol mandates use of *nix style paths (even if the actual remote server system uses a different syntax). So pysftp/Paramiko know how to convert a relative path to an absolute path.

On the contrary, a command passed to `.execute` methods is completely executed on the server using a proprietary syntax of the server. There's no way a local library can understand that and somehow magically convert it.

Answer (score -1):

If you type in sftp.execute('ls') you will get the contents of your usernames directory.

In that directory create a file called example.py and write the following:

import os
os.chdir('/home/alex_test')
os.system('source myscript.tcsh')

Now run: 

sftp.execute('python example.py')

Not the best solution but it works.

Comment: Why would you do that? Why don't you do `sftp.execute('cd /home/alex_test; ./myscript.tcsh')`? - Not to mention that this does not answer the question.